# How to add tooltip with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
    function getElements(list) {
        var checkList = document.getElementById(list);
        var items = document.getElementById(list + '_items');

        if (items.classList.contains('visible')) {
            items.classList.remove('visible');
            items.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            items.classList.add('visible');
            items.style.display = "block";
        }

    };

    $('html').click(function() {
      $('#list1_items').hide();
    });

    $('#list1').click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('#list2_items').hide();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('#list2_items').hide();
    });

    $('#list2').click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('#list1_items').hide();
    });
        
   let list1 = new Set();
   let list2 = new Set();

   document.querySelector('#list1_items').addEventListener('change', e => {
    e.target.checked ? list1.add(e.target.value) : list1.delete(e.target.value); 
     if(list1.size) document.querySelectorAll('#list2_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = true); 
     else document.querySelectorAll('#list2_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = false);
   });

   document.querySelector('#list2_items').addEventListener('change', e => {
    e.target.checked ? list2.add(e.target.value) : list2.delete(e.target.value); 
     if(list2.size) document.querySelectorAll('#list1_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = true);
     else
       document.querySelectorAll('#list1_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = false);
   });

$('select[name="employee_id"]').on('change', function() {
    console.log('inside script')
    var employee_id = document.getElementById('employee_id').selectedOptions[0].value;
    console.log(employee_id)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/kpiDetailsList",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          'employee_id': employee_id,
          }),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          var parsed_data = data;
          monthly_list = parsed_data.monthly_list;
          quarterly_list = parsed_data.quarterly_list;
          console.log(monthly_list.length)
          console.log(quarterly_list.length)

          if(monthly_list.length != 0 || quarterly_list.length != 0) {
          console.log('inside first if')
          $('#list1').css('pointer-events','');
          $('#list1_items').empty();
              for (index = 0; index < monthly_list.length; index++) { 
                $('#list1_items').append("<li><input type='checkbox' name='month' value='" + monthly_list[index] + "'id='" + monthly_list[index] + "'><label for='" + monthly_list[index] + "'>" + monthly_list[index] + "</label></li>");
            }
          $('#list2').css('pointer-events','');
          $('#list2_items').empty();
              for (index = 0; index < quarterly_list.length; index++) {
                if(quarterly_list[index] == 'Quarter1') {
                  $('#list2_items').append("<li><input type='checkbox' name='quarter' value='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'id='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'><label for='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'> Apr - Jun (Quarter 1) </label></li>");
                } 
                else if(quarterly_list[index] == 'Quarter2') {
                  $('#list2_items').append("<li><input type='checkbox' name='quarter' value='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'id='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'><label for='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'> Jul - Sep (Quarter 2) </label></li>");
                }
                else if(quarterly_list[index] == 'Quarter3') {
                  $('#list2_items').append("<li><input type='checkbox' name='quarter' value='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'id='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'><label for='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'> Oct - Dec (Quarter 3) </label></li>");
                } 
                else if(quarterly_list[index] == 'Quarter4') {
                  $('#list2_items').append("<li><input type='checkbox' name='quarter' value='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'id='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'><label for='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'> Jan - Mar (Quarter 4) </label></li>");
                } 
                else {
                  console.log('Data not found')
                } 
              }
            }
            else if (monthly_list.length == 0 && quarterly_list.length == 0) {
              console.log('inside second if')
                $('#list1').css('pointer-events','none');
                $("#list1").tooltip();
                $('#list2').css('pointer-events','none');
                $("#list2").attr("title", "Data not available");
            }
            else if (monthly_list.length == 0 || quarterly_list.length == 0) {
              console.log('inside third if')
                if (monthly_list.length == 0) {
                  console.log('inside monthly list')
                  $('#list1').css('pointer-events','none');
                  $("#list1").attr("title", "Data not available");
                } 
                else {
                  $('#list2').css('pointer-events','none');
                  $("#list2").attr("title", "Data not available");
                } 
            }
            else {
              console.log("data not found")
            }                  
        },
        error : function(e) {
          console.log("Error :"+e)
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 260px;
}


.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 230px;
  justify-content: right;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='34' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat ;
  background-position-x: 100% ;
  background-position-y: 5px;
}

.dropdown-check-list block{
  box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 260px;
}

#criteria {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='34' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat ;
  background-position-x: 100% ;
  background-position-y: 5px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* for Chrome */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}*/

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  z-index:99;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 230px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
  color: #0094ff;
}

.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1">
          <div class="custom-dropdown">
          <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list1&#39;)">Select Months</span>
          <div class="options">
          <ul id="list1_items" class="items" name="month" style="display: none;"><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Sep-2021" id="Sep-2021"><label for="Sep-2021">Sep-2021</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jun-2021" id="Jun-2021"><label for="Jun-2021">Jun-2021</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Aug-2021" id="Aug-2021"><label for="Aug-2021">Aug-2021</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jul-2021" id="Jul-2021"><label for="Jul-2021">Jul-2021</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="May-2021" id="May-2021"><label for="May-2021">May-2021</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Apr-2021" id="Apr-2021"><label for="Apr-2021">Apr-2021</label></li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
          <div class="custom-dropdown">
          <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list2&#39;)">Select Quarter</span>
          <div class="options">
          <ul id="list2_items" class="items" name="quarter" style="display: none;"><li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter1" id="Quarter1"><label for="Quarter1"> Apr - Jun (Quarter 1) </label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter2" id="Quarter2"><label for="Quarter2"> Jul - Sep (Quarter 2) </label></li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So my Jquery code is :

```
else if (monthly_list.length == 0 && quarterly_list.length == 0) {
          console.log('inside second if')
            $('#list1').css('pointer-events','none');
            $("#list1").attr("title", "Data not available");
            $('#list2').css('pointer-events','none');
            $("#list2").attr("title", "Data not available");
        }
        else if (monthly_list.length == 0 || quarterly_list.length == 0) {
          console.log('inside third if')
            if (monthly_list.length == 0) {
              console.log('inside monthly list')
              $('#list1').css('pointer-events','none');
              $("#list1").attr("title", "Data not available");
            } 
            else {
              $('#list2').css('pointer-events','none');
              $("#list2").attr("title", "Data not available");
            }
```

I tried this, for adding "Data not available" tooltip but this isnt working, if someone can please help me figure out where I am going wrong. Actually all of this is inside AJAX call, and if there is no data in the particular dropdown, I need to close the dropdown and hence `pointer-events,none` but also show a tooltip which isnt working.

Thankyou

Comment: This code is not runnable as it is. Please provide Minimal, Reproducible example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: No I didnt resolve it yet

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this code for creating tooltip:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

<p>Note that the position of the tooltip text isn't very good. Go back to the tutorial and continue reading on how to position the tooltip in a desirable way.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually my code works by calling AJAX request and therefore I need the tooltip only when there is no data by this method it shows always

Comment: You can remove tooltip class when you don't want to show tooltip. Also you can replace tooltiptext div's content with your ajax response.